# Puma and Rails - Prevent Duplicate Records WITHOUT Database Indexes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, validation, duplicates, puma

Recently, I've noticed that duplicate records are being created because of concurrent requests happening in different threads, resulting in records passing validations before being placed in the database. I would like to prevent this issue without using add_index because some of my validations require conditions which cannot be satisfied by using mysql indexes.

One idea I have is to somehow dedicate a thread to record creation, or at least from validations to the database. I do not know how to go about this though, or if it's even possible.

Help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).

Inside transaction

1. Check if record does not yet exist
2. Validate
3. Create record

Transactions lock database objects to ensure operation integrity. Parallel transaction will fail without changing your database if another one commits first.

This might have unwanted performance impact, especially if your validation/creation process is too expensive/long, because of locks and the fact that parallel transaction doomed to fail will still run to end. But this can be optimized based on your business logic.

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to my problem. I'm having this issue when there are simultaneous requests being made from the user end, and so there still are the multiple of the same requests. Is there something I am misunderstanding?

Comment: @user3739826 your end problem is duplicated records in database, no? This answer solves it. Your users can create as many same requests as they want, just one of them will end up creating database record.